Problem Deploying to Vercel using Plaiceholder, Sharp and NextJS 14
I wanted to blur my dynamic images that is already using Image component by NextJS 14.0.3.
Locally everything is fine. But when I try to deploy it on Vercel. It throws
corrupted size vs. prev_size
Error: Command "npm run build" exited with SIGABRT

What I've Tried

[X] Used the latest version of Plaiceholder and Sharp and followed the instructions of the official Plaiceholder website and it throws the above error (not even a successfull build)

[X] Downgraded Sharp to 0.32.6 (https://github.com/lovell/sharp/issues/3870) throws


Task timed out after 10.01 seconds

The latter error might come from Prisma while fetching data but without using sharp and plaiceholder package everything works fine.
Minimal codes
using sharp latest version: LATEST VERSION BRANCH
vercel build log:
using sharp version 0.32.6 would throw this error:


my blur image component is like this:
import Image, { ImageProps } from "next/image";
import { getPlaiceholder } from "plaiceholder";

export default async function BlurImage({ src, alt, ...rest }: ImageProps) {
  if (typeof src !== "string") return <Image src={src} alt={alt} {...rest} />;
  const buffer = await fetch(src).then(async (res) =>
    Buffer.from(await res.arrayBuffer())
  );
  const { base64 } = await getPlaiceholder(buffer);

  return (
    <Image
      alt={alt}
      src={src}
      placeholder='blur'
      blurDataURL={base64}
      {...rest}
    />
  );
}


Downgrading the sharp package to sharp@0.32.6 worked for me..

You can checkout this https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/60803#discussioncomment-8165517
